# How to sort unique values in of a particular coulmn in pandas?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have numerical values in `campaign_id` column. I want to sort the unique values in a that column but I am not able to do it.

I tried following:

`testdata['campaign_id'].unique.sort_values()`

OR

`testdata['campaign_id'].sort_values.unique()`

but above code gives error. How to sort the unique values of particular column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need for first [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html), because [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) return `numpy array`:

```
print (np.sort(testdata['campaign_id'].unique()))
```

If swap functions use:

```
print (testdata['campaign_id'].sort_values().unique())
```

**Sample**:

```
testdata = pd.DataFrame({'campaign_id':[7,1,1,4,2,3]})
print (testdata)
   campaign_id
0            7
1            1
2            1
3            4
4            2
5            3
print (np.sort(testdata['campaign_id'].unique()))
[1 2 3 4 7]

print (testdata['campaign_id'].sort_values().unique())
[1 2 3 4 7]
```